# Nokogiri giving me some trouble after adding AWS-SDK gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nokogiri

I added the **aws-sdk** to my `Gemfile` as followed: `gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.45.0'`
and then proceeded to run `bundle install` in the terminal. However, the bundle did not work correctly and was not able to complete successfully.

**command line prompt**

```
Building nokogiri using system libraries.

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
Building nokogiri using system libraries.
libxml2 version 2.9.0 and later is not yet supported, but proceeding anyway.
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
make: *** [html_document.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/nokogiri-1.6.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/cyrusghazanfar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.2.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.2.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.2.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.2.4'
gem 'paperclip', github: 'thoughtbot/paperclip'
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.45.0'


group :development, :test do
     gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
     gem 'pg'
     gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
```

**Nokogiri** is giving me some problem here and I can't figure out what exactly.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `make` can't find `/usr/bin/gcc-4.2`:

```
make: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2: No such file or directory
```

If you have Xcode and Command Line Tools installed, then `gcc` is in `/usr/bin`. To fix the issue with `make`, create a symlink for `gcc-4.2` which points to `gcc`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```